# Como pegar o nome de uma função callback em javascript?

Tags: javascript

Por exemplo:

```
function ola() {
    console.log("Olá =)");
}
function executar(callback) {
    // quero descobrir o nome deste callback que é passado para cá
   callback();
}

executar(ola);
```

Desse modo, a função executar irá executar (rsrs) o callback que, neste caso, é a função `ola()`. O que eu gostaria de saber é: como eu posso, dentro da função `executar()`, ter acesso ao nome real do callback (ola), já que nesse escopo eu apenas uso o alias "callback" para referenciar qualquer função passada como argumento?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para ter acesso ao nome: `callback.name`

```
function ola() {
    console.log("Olá =)");
}
function executar(callback) {
   console.log(callback.name);
   callback();
}

executar(ola);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!